# What is the reserved variables server which i need to use?

Tags: php, variables

What is the reserved variables server which i need to use if the current script was accessed http://www.example.com/index.php?task=myaccount
then the variables server will be /index.php?task=myaccount

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];`

Be sure to sanitize it if echo'ing it to the page (e.g. in a form's action attrib.)